# Show that $G$ has finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ if there exists homomorphism $\Phi:G \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$ with $\ker(\Phi)$ finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

The task is to show that, for $G$, an infinite group, if there exists homomorphism $\Phi:G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with $\ker(\Phi)$ finite, then $G$ contains finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I see that taking any $g \in G$ s.t. $\Phi(g) \neq 0$, the subgroup $\langle g\rangle $ must be isomorphic to some subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ - which has a form of $n \mathbb{Z}$, so it is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}$.

But how can I get a conclusion that $\langle g\rangle $ has finite index in $G$?

Comment: Take an element $g$ mapping to the integer $1$, and consider $\langle g\rangle Ker$.

Comment: @SteveD But how do I know that 1 is in image of $\Phi$? $Im(\Phi)$ can be for example $2\mathbb{Z}$, can't it?

Comment: Your second paragraph already takes care of that.